# Flask: TypeError: blog() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model "blog" and I am trying to create an Instance of it and add it to the database. However, when I try to create the instance I get the error `TypeError: blog() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'`, and when I delete the parameter user it says: `TypeError: blog() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'` and so on for all the parameters. 
Code: 
 
Model:

```
class blog(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = db.Column("user", db.String)
    title = db.Column("title", db.String())
    body = db.Column("body", db.String())
    images = db.Column("images", ScalarListType())
    def __init__(self, user, title, body, images):
        self.user = user
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
        self.images = images
```

function:

```
@app.route('/add_blog', defaults={'realfiles': ""}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/add_blog:<realfiles>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_blog(realfiles):
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.form["title"]
        body = request.form["body"]
        images = realfiles
        user = '1'
        new_blog = blog(user = user, title = title, body = body, images = images)
        for f in realfiles.split(','):
            os.rename(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static\\temp', f), os.path.join(app.root_path,'static\\uploads', f))
        db.session.add(new_blog)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f"added the blog {new_blog.title}!")
        return redirect(url_for("home"))
    if realfiles == "":
        return render_template("add_blog.html")
    return render_template("add_blog.html", realfiles=realfiles.split(','))
```

the parameter realfiles is a string.

EDIT:

I tried to change the names of the properties, to restart computer, delete database and create a new one, none of the above worked

EDIT 1:
I changed the variable to "name" instead of "user". Still not working.
Here is the full traceback

```html
TypeError
TypeError: blog() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\JoelBlog-UELb-k-q\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\JoelBlog-UELb-k-q\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\JoelBlog-UELb-k-q\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\JoelBlog-UELb-k-q\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\JoelBlog-UELb-k-q\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\JoelBlog-UELb-k-q\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\JoelBlog-UELb-k-q\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\JoelBlog-UELb-k-q\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\JoelBlog-UELb-k-q\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\JoelBlog-UELb-k-q\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "D:\Google Drive\PythonProjects\JoelBlog\app.py", line 96, in add_blog
new_blog = blog(name = user, title = title, body = body, images = images)
TypeError: blog() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Can you help?
Thanks

Comment: Did you redefine `blog` somewhere up in your code or have two imports of `blog` that are completely different types?

Comment: No, I just checked again

Comment: Please, your class name should be Blog not blog, it's confusing. You should not have __init__ there too. Or you must call the super class init too.

Comment: The problem could come from your db.String that should be db.String(). String is a class, String() is an object. and your database may expect an length.

Comment: @Victor I added the () to the string, and everything worked, The init did not need to be removed. If you write it as an answer I can accept it!

Comment: I'll do it if I have time, and you are right about init. In the SQLAlchemy docs, it's written we are free to use init, because SQlAlchemy use a lower method "new" to instantiate the object. But I think in your case, you probably do not need it, unless you want to check the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is failing because you have a **init** function which does not expect key/value arguments. If there wasn't an **init** then you could call it as you are trying. Based on how you're calling you would use def **init**(self, **kwargs), then kwargs.get(...).

```
class blog(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = db.Column("user", db.String)
    title = db.Column("title", db.String())
    body = db.Column("body", db.String())
    images = db.Column("images", ScalarListType())
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.get('user')
        self.title = kwargs.get('title')
        self.body = kwargs.get('body')
        self.images = kwargs.get('images')
```